# Importing csv to R, extract polygon and decode it with googlePolylines packages

Tags: r, decode, google-polyline

I have been trying to decode encrypted google polygons with R using the googlePolylines package which I have achieved by setting the polygon as a text but cannot do the same procedure by importing a csv file with the polygons.

For example, I have the following code:

```
library(googlePolylines)
pol<-"j~thAxdvtMtXmL|LgCpKxCjQzD~T`GzXrAlMePnDsKpVoF`QgBnNoM~IcA`JiGnd@iYvZuLzKkSlH_d@wDef@iJwFyZfUmc@hCsa@N{\\|SeCzOaFgQwD{SaPiC|WwBpPr@bGsG{FeQxEkOtXa@dXgFtHyJoIiGui@NqaAvFuRyQxEia@he@u_@b\\og@dHuZyJaX_d@zK_Ua@eBwMq`A}AyRcTkKce@c]uWeS{DuRzZtCh]|b@zGuCbm@fUdTsLbS__@wBoTlu@zVbm@dc@l]oExn@gf@vUgPbAkL|HtCnXi@zKtRvc@CzPxBpLxAnEvFvDpPx^cFlBTh@??Dn@@f@~G|QFH~\\gMj@Su@}@"
polylines<-c(pol)
coordinates<-decode(polylines)
```

This works but for this I have to change manually the encrypted polygon. What I want to do is to import a csv (datapolygons.csv) with the encrypted polygon (column polygon) and then decode it. I have tried with the following code but it gives me an error message.

datapolygons.csv (polygon is written the same as the previous encoded polygon)

store_id | store_name | polygon

12345    | RANDOM     | "j~thAxdvtMtXmL....."

```
library(googlePolylines)
polyfile=read.table('datapolygon.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
pol<-levels(droplevels(polyfile$polygon))
polylines<-c(pol)
coordinates<-decode(polylines)
```

Error message:
Error in rcpp_decode_polyline(polylines, "coords") : 
  basic_string::at: __n (which is 363) >= this->size() (which is 363)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Gerardos, can you provided a sample of the object `polyfile`, for example with `dput(head(polyfile))`?

Comment: Hi Ian, I get this: structure(list(store_address_id = 12345L, store_name = structure(1L, .Label = "RANDOM", class = "factor"), 
    polygon = structure(1L, .Label = "\"j~thAxdvtMtXmL|LgCpKxCjQzD~T`GzXrAlMePnDsKpVoF`QgBnNoM~IcA`JiGnd@iYvZuLzKkSlH_d@wDef@iJwFyZfUmc@hCsa@N{\\\\|SeCzOaFgQwD{SaPiC|WwBpPr@bGsG{FeQxEkOtXa@dXgFtHyJoIiGui@NqaAvFuRyQxEia@he@u_@b\\\\og@dHuZyJaX_d@zK_Ua@eBwMq`A}AyRcTkKce@c]uWeS{DuRzZtCh]|b@zGuCbm@fUdTsLbS__@wBoTlu@zVbm@dc@l]oExn@gf@vUgPbAkL|HtCnXi@zKtRvc@CzPxBpLxAnEvFvDpPx^cFlBTh@??Dn@@f@~G|QFH~\\\\gMj@Su@}@\"", class = "factor")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Comment: Sorry for the formatting I don't really know how to fix it

Comment: The problem is there are backticks (the same character on ~) in the string that are messing up the markdown syntax.

Comment: Yeah the encoded polygon has a weird list of characters and it starts with an " and ends with the same symbol so I think that may be the problem but don't really know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the string is corrupt in your `.csv` file? Perhaps when you made the data.frame to write out? The corruption seems to occur during conversion to `factor()`.

I have no trouble writing it out and back in:

```
polyfile <- data.frame(store_address_id = 12345, 
                       store_name = "RANDOM",
                       polygon = "j~thAxdvtMtXmL|LgCpKxCjQzD~T`GzXrAlMePnDsKpVoF`QgBnNoM~IcA`JiGnd@iYvZuLzKkSlH_d@wDef@iJwFyZfUmc@hCsa@N{\\|SeCzOaFgQwD{SaPiC|WwBpPr@bGsG{FeQxEkOtXa@dXgFtHyJoIiGui@NqaAvFuRyQxEia@he@u_@b\\og@dHuZyJaX_d@zK_Ua@eBwMq`A}AyRcTkKce@c]uWeS{DuRzZtCh]|b@zGuCbm@fUdTsLbS__@wBoTlu@zVbm@dc@l]oExn@gf@vUgPbAkL|HtCnXi@zKtRvc@CzPxBpLxAnEvFvDpPx^cFlBTh@??Dn@@f@~G|QFH~\\gMj@Su@}@",
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

write.csv(file="~/test.csv",polyfile)
polyfile2 <- read.table('~/test.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
decode(polyfile2$polygon)
[[1]]
         lat       lon
1  -12.07286 -76.95965
2  -12.07697 -76.95750
3  -12.07920 -76.95682
4  -12.08121 -76.95759
5  -12.08415 -76.95853
6  -12.08767 -76.95982
7  -12.09181 -76.96024
8  -12.09412 -76.95749
9  -12.09500 -76.95547
10 -12.09877 -76.95427
```

Comment: Hi Ian, unfortunately I still get the same message error

Comment: I think your `.csv` file might be corrupt. See my edit.

Comment: Yes it was corrupt and I had to delete the first and last " in the csv file. Thank you it works perfectly now.